# How might I generalize this code to fit larger sets of data?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to extend the usability of the code i've written. even better, I would like to generalize it for future use.

I am using Rstudio. I have recoded a 100-dimensional vector. Values 1-10 have been converted to identity vectors. For instance, all values of 1 are now vectors that read 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, and all values of 2 now read 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, and so on. Here is the code:

```
tens <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)
y <- sample(tens, size=100, replace=TRUE)
y
num.its <- 100
Y <- rep(0,num.its*10)
dim(Y) <- c(num.its,10)
I <- diag(10)
for(i in 1:100){
  if(y[i]==1){
    Y[i,] <- I[1,]
  } else if (y[i]==2){
    Y[i,] <- I[2,]
  } else if (y[i]==3){
    Y[i,] <- I[3,]
  } else if (y[i]==4){
    Y[i,] <- I[4,]
  } else if (y[i]==5){
    Y[i,] <- I[5,]
  } else if (y[i]==6){
    Y[i,] <- I[6,]
  } else if (y[i]==7){
    Y[i,] <- I[7,]
  } else if (y[i]==8){
    Y[i,] <- I[8,]
  } else if (y[i]==9){
    Y[i,] <- I[9,]
  } else {
    Y[i,] <- I[10,]
  }
}
```

The code works as planned. however, if I had to recode values of 1-2000, then I would rather not write 2000 else if statements. Any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: `Y[i,] = I[min(y[i],10),]`? That is if `y[i]>0` in all cases

Comment: thank you for responding. What i am looking to generalize is the number of different values of y i could have. In this specific case, I have 10 different possible values to recode, but in another case, i may have 100 or 200. thank you

Comment: `Y[i,] = I[y[i],]` is what you are looking for

Comment: note that `min` is necessary to replicate the behaviour of your code since you used `else` instead of `else if` for the last condition but you can raise 10 to an arbitrary number here

Comment: @OganM there are only 10 values in `y` ie `1:10` if there could have been other values other than `1:10` then the `min` would have been deemed necessary

Answer (score 1):

A pretty decent one-liner is the following:

```
# sample data
set.seed(1234)
x <- c(1:5, sample(10L, 6))
```

Our vector is

```
x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 10  6  5  4  1  8
```

Then, convert x to a factor variable, specifying the desired levels, and use `model.matrix` to get a matrix of your desired vectors.

```
model.matrix(~ . + 0, data.frame(x=factor(x, levels=1:10)))
```

This returns

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
1   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
5   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
7   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
8   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
9   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
10  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
11  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
attr(,"assign")
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$x
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Here, the rows represent what you want. You can use `t` to convert this to columns if desired. Note also that even though 7 is missing in x, that column is present in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `dummy` from the package `dummy`

```
dummy::dummy(data.frame(x=factor(x)))
   x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_8 x_9
1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
5    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
6    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
7    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
9    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```